# Orange data mining: Skip first lines in multiple files

Tags: line, skip, orange

I use Orange 3.22. The first step in my model is to load about 150 files with *Spectroscopy.Multifile*.  In all files the relevant information starts only from line 22. In *Data.CSVFileImport* I can skip single lines. How can I skip the first 21 lines **in Orange** in all files? I already have a Python solution outside of Orange.

Best regards